# Fatal error : Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted

Tags: php, mysql, database

PHP version 7.1 
I am trying to create a page where any user can upload an image, their name, comment, and their email. On the webpage, only the user name, comment and the image they uploaded will show up on the webpage. I am not sure if this will help with anything but I am using the Hostgator MySQL database to store all the data. The warning I get is:

**Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4294967296 bytes) in on line 49**

I have made another post on this website regarding this same issue and I have been trying to follow other similar answers as well steps but it is not working and I did not get a proper answer on my last post either. I would appreciate it if someone can guide me through this issue. Thanks in advance.

I will include my entire PHP code for this project. I do not have a php.ini file but I can make one if needed. In one post on this website, it said to just put the line "ini_set('memory_limit', '256M'); before or after the specific error line so instead of creating a php.ini file I just put the line in my actual code. 
"

The codes the error is referring to:

```
$sql = "SELECT imgFullNameGallery, titleGallery, descGallery FROM gallery ORDER BY orderGallery 
DESC;";

        $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
        if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
          echo "SQL statement failed!";
        } else {

          mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);



          mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $imgFullNameGallery, $titleGallery, $descGallery);


 ini_set('memory_limit', '256M');

          while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
  echo '<a href="#">
  <div style="background-image: url(img/gallery/'.$imgFullNameGallery.');"></div>
  <h3>'.$titleGallery.'</h3>
  <p>'.$descGallery.'</p>
  </a>';
  }
        }
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
        mysqli_close($link);
        ?>
```

The entire code that uploads and gets data from database to display them on the webpage is below:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$newFileName = $_POST['filename'];
if (empty($newFileName)) {
$newFileName = "gallery";
} else {
$newFileName = strtolower(str_replace(" ", "-", $newFileName));
}
$imageTitle = $_POST['filetitle'];
$imageDesc = $_POST['filedesc'];

$file = $_FILES['file'];

$fileName = $file["name"];
$fileType = $file["type"];
$fileTempName = $file["tmp_name"];
$fileError = $file["error"];
$fileSize = $file["size"];

$fileExt = explode(".", $fileName);
$fileActualExt = strtolower(end($fileExt));

$allowed = array("jpg", "jpeg", "png");

if (in_array($fileActualExt, $allowed)) {
if ($fileError === 0) {
  if ($fileSize < 5000000) {
    $imageFullName = $newFileName . "." . uniqid("", true) . "." . $fileActualExt;
    $fileDestination = "../img/gallery/" . $imageFullName;

    include_once "dbh.inc.php";

    if (empty($imageTitle) || empty($imageDesc)) {
      header("Location: ../gallery.php?upload=empty");
      exit();
    } else {
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM gallery;";
      $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
      if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
        echo "SQL statement failed!";
      } else {
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
        $rowCount = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        $setImageOrder = $rowCount + 1;

        $sql = "INSERT INTO gallery (titleGallery, descGallery, imgFullNameGallery, orderGallery) 
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?);";
        if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
          echo "SQL statement failed!";
        } else {
          mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssss", $imageTitle, $imageDesc, $imageFullName, 
$setImageOrder);
          mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

          move_uploaded_file($fileTempName, $fileDestination);

          header("Location: ../gallery.php?upload=success");
        }
      }
    }
  } else {
    echo "File size is too big!";
    exit();
  }
  } else {
  echo "You had an error!";
  exit();
 }
 } else {
 echo "You need to upload a proper file type!";
 exit();
 }

 }
```

?>

Comment: ini_set('memory_limit', '256M'); Did you increased this to  512 or 768. Besides You should try to limit the filesize or the number of mages to retrieve.

Comment: yea I tried changing it to 512 and 768 as well as limiting filesize but it still gives same error.

Comment: Usually increasing the memory limit is not the solution, you should figure out why you're using so much memory in the first place and fix that.

Comment: How many rows are in the `gallery` table?

Comment: I am sorry I new to MySQL so I was trying to determine how many rows my database actually had before answering you. So far there is nothing in the database. The whole idea is that as a user enters the necessary information needed for the form they webpage will call back every row that exists. There is a total of 5 columns. I am not sure if this is what you are asking if it is not let me know so I can give a better answer.